# Camel replace all CRLF with LF using Simple DSL

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to replace the CRLF of the input data with LF but this is breaking the route. My code is as shown below

```
from(fromEndpoint)
    .convertBodyTo(byte[].class, "iso-8859-1")
    .setBody(simple("body.replaceAll(\r\n, \n)"))....
```

if I take the setbody out it works perfect. I just want platform dependent line feeds

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Stack trace of your error might be useful. Anyway I think you sholud add ${ at beginning of simple expression and } at the end. Also don't forget to quote your \r\n and \n as string literals.

Comment: What Camel version do you use. Also you should have ' around the parameters to replaceAll, eg '\r\n','\n'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solved with this

```
from(fromEndpoint)
    .convertBodyTo(byte[].class, "iso-8859-1")
    .setBody(body().regexReplaceAll("\\r\\n", "\\\n"))
```