# Replace colon in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am getting data from a jms queue named "accounting", and writing it to a file with the name id.xml.

Example filename: ID:dellmachine-37527-1508835786225-1:2:1:1:1.xml

What i want: ID_dellmachine-37527-1508835786225-1_2_1_1_1.xml

I want to replace the colon with underscore. Is this possible?

This is my Camel route:

```
from("jms:accounting")
.log("### Consumed from jms:accounting ###")
.to("file:src/main/resources/data/work_in_progress?fileName=${id}.xml");
```

Comment: What message broker are you using? And what version of Camel do you use?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508716/camel-replace-all-crlf-with-lf-using-simple-dsl